# Python Fenwick Tree

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, time-limit-exceeded, tree

I am trying to solve this question: https://open.kattis.com/problems/fenwick

> A Fenwick Tree (also known as a Binary Indexed Tree) is a data
>   structure on an array which enables fast ((log)) updates and
>   prefix sum queries on the underlying data.
>
> For this problem, implement a Fenwick Tree to support operations of
>   two types: (a) increment an element in the array or (b) query the
>   prefix sum of a portion of the array.
>
> Input The first line of input contains two integers , , where
>   1≤≤5000000 is the length of the array and 0≤≤5000000 is the number
>   of operations. Then follow  lines giving the operations. There are
>   two types of operations:
>
> “+  ” indicates that [] is incremented by , where 0≤<
>   and −10^9≤≤10^9 (both are integers)
>
> “? ” is a query for the value of [0]+[1]+…+[−1], where
>   0≤≤ (for =0 this is interpreted as an empty sum)
>
> You should assume that every array entry is initially 0.

My implementation:

```
class SegmentTree:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.nums = [0] * n
        self.tree = {}
        self._build()

    def _build(self):
        def build(l, r, index):
            if l == r:
                self.tree[index] = self.nums[l]
            else:
                mid = (l+r)//2
                build(l, mid, index*2)
                build(mid+1, r, index*2+1)
                self.tree[index] = self.tree[index*2] + self.tree[index*2+1]

        build(0, len(self.nums)-1, 1)

    def get_sum(self, i, j):
        def get_sum(left_boundary, right_boundary, index, i, j):
            if j < i:
                return 0

            if left_boundary == right_boundary:
                return self.tree[index]
            if left_boundary == i and right_boundary == j:
                return self.tree[index]
            else:
                mid = (left_boundary + right_boundary)//2
                left_sum = get_sum(left_boundary, mid, index*2, i, min(j, mid))
                right_sum = get_sum(mid+1, right_boundary,
                                    index*2+1, max(i, mid+1), j)

                return left_sum + right_sum

        return get_sum(0, len(self.nums)-1, 1, i, j)

    def update(self, pos, num):
        def update(l, r, index):
            if l == r and l == pos:
                self.tree[index] = num
            else:
                mid = (l+r)//2
                if pos <= mid:
                    update(l, mid, index*2)
                else:
                    update(mid+1, r, index*2+1)
                self.tree[index] = self.tree[index*2] + self.tree[index*2+1]
        update(0, len(self.nums)-1, 1)


def main():

    n, q = map(int, input().split())
    nums = [0] * n
    s = SegmentTree(n)

    def update(ops):
        plus, i, inc = ops.split()
        i = int(i)
        inc = int(inc)
        s.nums[i] += inc
        s.update(i, s.nums[i])

    def prefix_sum(ops):
        q, j = ops.split()
        j = int(j)
        ans = s.get_sum(0, j-1)
        print(ans)

    for _ in range(q):
        ops = input()
        if len(ops.split()) == 3:
            update(ops)
        else:
            prefix_sum(ops)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This sadly times out. How do I optimize it to run faster?

Answer (score 1):

Segment trees and Fenwick trees are usually implemented as [implicit
data
structures](https://www.wisdomjobs.com/e-university/data-structures-tutorial-290/implicit-data-structure-7118.html). That
is, as an array with the tree structure implicitly given by the array
indices. Your code instead stores the tree as a Python dictionary
which is very inefficient.

The second problem with your segment tree is that you are using
recursion. Refer to this [sample
code](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/18051) for how to implement
iterative versions of `get_sum` and `update`.

The third problem is that you have implemented a Segment tree and not
a Fenwick tree (aka Binary indexed tree). For this problem, they are
slightly more efficient than Segment trees.

The fourth problem is, sadly, Python. :) Number crunching code and
tight loops just doesn't run as fast in Python as they do in
lower-level languages. Plus, in this problem, IO and number parsing is
dominating.

Here is a Python solution using a Fenwick tree:

```
n, q = map(int, input().split())
# One extra element so that we can use 1-based indexing.
nums = [0] * (n + 1)
for _ in range(q):
    parts = input().split()
    if len(parts) == 3:
        _, i, inc = parts[0], int(parts[1]) + 1, int(parts[2])
        while i <= n:
            nums[i] += inc
            i += i & (-i)
    else:
        _, i = parts[0], int(parts[1])
        tot = 0
        while i > 0:
            tot += nums[i]
            i -= i & (-i)
        print(tot)
```

If you port it to a low-level language it will be very fast.